# Dropping or emptying tables on SSDT publish

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, publish, sql-server-data-tools

I may just be stupid and missing something simple, but how do I make it so when I publish my SSDT project, it either empties or drops the tables in my DB without actually setting the 'CreateNewDatabase' setting to true in my publishing profile.

I have some post deploy inserts that run every time i publish which results in duplicate rows every time.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, every time you deploy you want to clear out the contents of all tables as you have a load of insert statements in the post-deploy scripts to create the data you want and so you want the tables to be empty?

If that is right then that isn’t the way ssdt is normally used, typically the important bit in a database is the data so you wouldn’t want to clear every table on publish so there isn’t anything built in, other than create new database.

That being said if you don’t need any data then you are in a great position, most problems we have is trying to make sure we don’t delete any data by accident :)

There are a couple of approaches, you could change your insert statements to merge statements, there is a proc called sp_generate_merge that you can get from github which generates a merge statement that you can use, this will make your tables look like the data in your post-deploy scripts and is my preferred.

If tables have more than around 2,000 rows then merge statements might not be right so I would just do a delete of truncate table before inserting my data.

Hope I got the question right :)

Ed